# How to run AngularJS on a web Server which invokes SQL Server Database Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json, angularjs

I'm building my first `Angular` application with .NET.

I use `VS 2012` and `C#` and `SQL Server 2012`.

I'm really excited about this but, despite the almost daunting amount of tutorials and docs available, I can't find a clear explanation of how to retrieve the data from SQL server and display it in my app.

I have been playing around a bit with [Dan Wahlin's Customer Manager app](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManagerStandard), but this is built with `Entity Framework` and `BreezeJS`, which are both new to me.

I have also tried to follow [this Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567376/ConnectingplustoplusDatabaseplusUsingplusAngularJS) which builds communication with the server via a standard web service and what looks like an `ajax` call to retrieve some `json`.

However there is no server side code to deserialize the SQL into Json (which I assume is necessary).

This is what I would like:

- an example of how to connect my Angular app to SQL Server DB.
- the example should mention the steps involved to achieve that.

I don't expect a comprehensive list of *all* the possible ways of doing this and I'm not asking you to do it for me.

I'm just hoping for a way good enough to get me started.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to set up an API on your server, then, yes, there are tons of server-side libraries to convert POCO to JSON, once you deserialize your data rows into those.

Comment: do you mean how to run `AngularJS on a web Server which Invokes Sql Server Database Calls`

Comment: @MatthewHaugen thanks for the comment, but could you provide a bit more details?

Comment: I've edited my question trying to narrow its scope and incorporating some advice from comments.

Comment: I have a similar problem, because each and every written or copied tutorial uses the same approach --> go for data from NoSQL DB. But this is not acceptable in all cases to get data fast at the price of loosening ACID. But perhaps I got your question wrong. Either you mean SQL calls at all or Best Practices in communication with a SQL database from a dynamic website made with AngularJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of different ways to connect to a SQL Server database with .NET and serve it to a web application built with AngularJS.

To get started, I'd recommend using Entity Framework to connect to your SQL Server database and serve the data with Web API 2. Here's a tutorial provided by Microsoft on this topic

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1

Once you have a web service available, you'll be able to use the `$http` or `$resource` services in AngularJS to get data from that web service.

As for the other ways, you can connect to a SQL Server database with other .NET data access technologies such as NHibernate, Dapper, ADO.NET. And you can serve that data via a web service with other technologies like WCF, ServiceStack or ASMX. And you can even use non-.NET web server technologies to connect to a SQL Server database if you really want to. For example, there's an mssql package for node.js.

Comment: thanks, that the sort of thing I'm after. I'll definitely check the tutorial. Could you perhaps sketch what are the other "different ways" you're referring to?